# How to auto size a row height in apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to adjust the height of a row depending on the content. 
Is there a method like `cell.autoSizeColumn()` to do this?

Comment: [this mailing list post](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Autosize-row-for-HSSF-library-td2308264.html) might help.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You might be able to use a for loop:

```
totalCells = cell.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
for(ii=0;ii<totalCells;ii++){
     Write your build code here
}
```

The help docs from the site helped a lot too.